# Are there any appearance changes to 3DS cartridges for the Nintendo Selects incarnations?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, version-differences

Awhile back, I lost my copy of Animal Crossing New Leaf, and I'm considering buying the Nintendo Selects version as a replacement.

However, my concern is that I might find my lost cartridge after buying the Nintendo Selects and I'll get the two cartridges confused.

Do Nintendo Selects variations of 3DS games have appearance differences on the cartridge's label? I know the package has differences, but I wish to know if it is the same case for the physical cartridge.

Comment: Are there any games aside from Animal Crossing that you have in mind? Using their tags might be better than just using the 3ds tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, the cartridges are the same.

> Never has and probably never will be. Players choice games didn't have it starting with the GameCube and neither did Nintendo selects Wii games.

Source [Gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/73494364) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/49ojhp/do_nintendo_selects_have_different_cartridge_art/).